# Get Network path for files in Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, networking, file-io

I am using Qt's `QFileDialog` to let user add files, but I run into issues adding files from network drives. The path I get from `getOpenFileName()` function is always local one. So if a network share `\\share1` is mounted in Windows as `J:\`, I will get a path starting with `J:\`.

This is not useful because people may have the same share mounted under different letter and when one user adds a path to the DB I want the other users to be able to access that path without guessing which server it's supposed to be on.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, when you mount remote directory as a local dirve, file system does not know, it's not local. Is it possible to copy such file to a place, accesible to everyone, and store a new path in you db?

Comment: The [QSystemStorageInfo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility/qsystemstorageinfo.html) class (part of the Qt Mobility add-on) almost does it. It can return the GUID for local drives and tell you what type of drive it is (local, network, etc), but the class method [uriForDrive uses GetVolumeNameForVolumeMountPoint](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility/qt-mobility/blobs/v1.2.0/src/systeminfo/qsysteminfo_win.cpp) which doesn't work on drives mapped to network paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you cannot make this with Qt alone, you need to use WinAPI. Check if the path contains `:` character and then find out the network path using [WNetGetConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Is there an example of using that somewhere? My google-fu is failing me. I never had to interact with the native windows API before.

Comment: Here is a C++ example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385374%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Also googling with words `WNetGetConnection` and `QString` produces good results.